# Stimulus controller action fires twice on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

For some reason, my stimulus controller, load once, but the action is fired twice on click.
I can't find where the issue is...

My code is pretty simple though, so I will share it below:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/application.js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
const application = Application.start()
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application
export { application }
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js
import { application } from "controllers/application"
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/radio_button_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static classes = [ 'active', 'inactive', 'invisible' ]

  connect() {
    console.log('connected to ', this.element.querySelector('input').value)
  }

  markAsChecked(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('-', this.element.querySelector('input').value);
  }
}
```

```html
// view.html.erb

<div class="flex flex-1 gap-x-8 justify-start">
  <label data-controller="radio-button" data-action="click->radio-button#markAsChecked:stop">
    <input type="radio" value="public" name="destination[access_type]" id="destination_access_type_public">
  </label>
  <label data-controller="radio-button" data-action="click->radio-button#markAsChecked:stop">
    <input type="radio" value="private" name="destination[access_type]" id="destination_access_type_private">
  </label>
  <label data-controller="radio-button" data-action="click->radio-button#markAsChecked:stop">
    <input type="radio" value="backend" name="destination[access_type]" id="destination_access_type_backend">
  </label>
</div>
```

When I run the following commands in the developer console, I also get double action firing

```js
// developer console
temp1 // label
temp1.click()
// - public
// - public
temp2 // input
temp2.click()
// - public
```

As you can see, markAsChecked is triggered twice when I click on the label, and once when I click on the input. I have no idea why...
(I expect it to always trigger once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default `<label>` element behavior:

> When a user clicks or touches/taps a label, the browser passes the focus to its associated input (**the resulting event is also raised for the input**)...

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label*

> ...clicking the `label` in the following snippet could trigger the user agent to **fire a `click` event at the `input`** element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user:
>
> ```html
> <label><input type=checkbox name=lost> Lost</label>
> ```

*https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element*

---

Note that when clicking a `<label>` you get two events but `event.target` is different:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log(event.target);
})
```

```html
<label for="destination_access_type_public">click me</label>
<input type="radio" value="public" name="destination[access_type]" id="destination_access_type_public">
```

You can add `data-action` to `input` to always get a single event:

```html
<label data-controller="radio-button">
  <input data-action="click->radio-button#markAsChecked" type="radio" value="public" name="destination[access_type]" id="destination_access_type_public">
</label>
```